# Wikipedia wrong on modular forms & line bundles?

Tags: riemann-surfaces, modular-forms, line-bundles

The current (25/03/2023 12:30 UTC) version of [the Wikipedia article on modular forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_form) has a section "[As sections of a line bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_form#As_sections_of_a_line_bundle)" where it claims the following:

> [image: screenshot from this section]

I think there are two mistakes in this section:

1. It uses the canonical bundle $\omega$. But this realizes only modular forms of *even* weight, and you have to take the $\frac{k}{2}$th power of it. That is, a weight $k$ modular form with $k$ even can be seen as a $\frac{k}{2}$-fold differential form, i.e., a section of $\omega^{\otimes (k/2)}$. 
   (One might suspect that Wikipedia just uses the definition that weight $k$ modular forms in their sense are weight $2k$ modular forms in my sense, but looking just a few lines above you can see that weight $k$ means it satisfies the transformation rule $f(\gamma \,z) = (cz + d)^k f(z)$, i.e., its my definition of weight $k$.)
2. It writes an *equality* $M_k(\Gamma) = H^0(X_\Gamma, \omega^{\otimes k})$. But the "holomorphic at every point" condition of a modular form does *not* transform to "holomorphic at every point" for the associated differential. That is because the chart at cusps and elliptic points is not the identity, which adds additional poles for the differential. In particular, the differential associated to a modular form is generally not holomorphic, but can have certain orders of poles at the cusps and elliptic points.

Could somebody confirm these mistakes? Or am *I* wrong?

Comment: This is sloppiness, in particular, confusing complex orbicurves and curves. In general, you should not trust Wikipedia too much since anybody can edit it no matter how little do they know about the subject.

Comment: If you conclude that there are errors, and they are easy to correct (especially if you have a book or other similar source to which you can cite the correction), please fix the Wikipedia article!

Comment: Hi Johann! Whoever wrote that probably intended "a canonical line bundle" to mean "some naturally defined line bundle", not "*the* canonical line bundle" as in the sheaf of regular differential forms. I think that should answer both of your questions

Comment: Oh right, I completely overread that it reads "*a* canonical line bundle"; thanks!